# how to modify .htaccess file to always redirect to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to modify my .htaccess file so that when someone comes into my site without typing www the site always redirects them to the www version.  For example, if my url is www.abc.com and they just type abc.com, I want to redirect them to abc.com.

Here is my current htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>
```

Normally I know how to do the redirect, but im having issues since it already has those few lines in there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add something like this immediately after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: You missed the $ after ^(.*)

Comment: @KnocksX It isn't necessary as `*` is greedy.

Answer (score 36):

I use the code below. It can be used for any domain name. You just need to enter it in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(edited to have all the code in the same block)

Comment: I like this answer most than the accepted one, no need to define domain.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods available

1) use mod_alias apache module

Redirect permanent /something http://yourwebsite.com/something

2) Add the following entry in your .htaccess / http.conf / yourwebsite.conf in the webserver configuarion directory

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourwebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com$1 [R=permanent,L]

Answer (score 1):

If you want redirect  example.com  to www.example.com you can try below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```