# Where to add www redirect code in a existing bbpress htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, bbpress

I recently installed bbpress on a domain of mine. and it came with a .htaccess file which looks like this ->

```
# BEGIN bbPress

Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /forum.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/?$ /forum.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ / [R=302,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /topic.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)/?$ /topic.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/?$ / [R=302,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /tags.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/?$ /tags.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/?$ /tags.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&tab=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&tab=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/?$ /profile.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /view.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/?$ /view.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/?$ /rss.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/topics/?$ /rss.php?topics=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/forum/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?forum=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/forum/([^/]+)/topics/?$ /rss.php?forum=$1&topics=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/topic/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?topic=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/tags/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/tags/([^/]+)/topics/?$ /rss.php?tag=$1&topics=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/profile/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/view/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END bbPress
```

Now I want to add a non-www to www redirect code in it, which is ->

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Where should I put it? I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159088/how-to-modify-htaccess-file-to-always-redirect-to-www) that I should put it right after `RewriteEngine On` but doing so makes the UI break. CSS file locations break.
So where should I put it?

Comment: Probably after the line `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Now `example.com` returns 301.. Not redirecting.. but `www.example.com` works fine..

Comment: Okay.. Put it after `RewriteBase /` and changed `[R=301]` to `[L,QSA]` and its working fine.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final `.htaccess` file that's working -

```
# BEGIN bbPress

Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /forum.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)/?$ /forum.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum/?$ / [R=302,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /topic.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]+)/?$ /topic.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^topic/?$ / [R=302,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /tags.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)/?$ /tags.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/?$ /tags.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&tab=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&tab=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^profile/?$ /profile.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ /view.php?view=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/?$ /view.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/?$ /rss.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/topics/?$ /rss.php?topics=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/forum/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?forum=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/forum/([^/]+)/topics/?$ /rss.php?forum=$1&topics=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/topic/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?topic=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/tags/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/tags/([^/]+)/topics/?$ /rss.php?tag=$1&topics=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/profile/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss/view/([^/]+)/?$ /rss.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END bbPress
```

Changing the `[R=301]` part to `[L,QSA]` solved the 301 error part..