# Something wrong in my .htaccess/mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Next simple rule at .htaccess for redirect all requests with non-www to www:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and when check it with the URL of kind

```
http://example.com/something
```

this redirect me to

```
http://www./something
```

seems that RewriteCond works, but there is nothing in result of regular expression, where as i think must be the host name without www. What's wrong - who knows?

Variants of rules with redirect to concrete host, like:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and other alike variants works fine.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you wanting to add a rewrite so all of the pages on your site load without the www. in the address bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159088/how-to-modify-htaccess-file-to-always-redirect-to-www

Comment: The question is why '%1' is empty. Problem is in negated pattern as describe @Michael-Berkowski in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of capturing the `HTTP_HOST` into `%1` with `(.*)` (which isn't working for you), just substitute `%{HTTP_HOST}` in the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The way you had it, your `%1` is not populated because of the `!` negation, it would seem.

#### From [the `RewriteRule` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> When using the NOT character to negate a pattern, you cannot include grouped wildcard parts in that pattern. This is because, when the pattern does NOT match (ie, the negation matches), there are no contents for the groups. Thus, if negated patterns are used, you cannot use $N in the substitution string!

Comment: +1 Did not see your last sentence and answered the same. I guess should be in bold.

Comment: That is! Thank you for such detailed information! Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This standard way of doing this seems to be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

This is how [mediatemple](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs), [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/all-non-www-urls-redirect-to-www-url), etc. recommend their users setup their .htaccess files.

Comment: Yes, right, without negotiation, it works - i know, thank you anyway.